# JavaScript Filter is not returning any value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I am collecting data from database to reduce my number of queries. I am fetching data from Moodle External Web Api
below is my data
`0 : {id: 4, userid: 3, instaceid: 1, courseid: 2, coursename: 'Web Development Basics', …} 1 : {id: 5, userid: 2, instaceid: 1, courseid: 2, coursename: 'Web Development Basics', …}` 
Now I want to 4 selects, and I want to filter values based on user's selection.
first select contains courseid - which i am able to show but as soon as I select course list, its not showing me associated user with the courseid like if I select Courseid with 2 value its should give me two user's 3,4

```
Ajax.call([request])[0].done(function(data) {
    // Populate the course select element
    const courseSelect = document.getElementById('course-select');
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(courseSelect);
    const courseIds = [...new Set(data.fetchData.map(item => item.courseid))];
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(courseIds);
    courseIds.forEach(courseId => {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = courseId;
        option.textContent = courseId;
        courseSelect.appendChild(option);
    });
    
    courseSelect.addEventListener('change', handleCourseSelection);

    // Function to handle course selection
    /**
     * @param {int} event iid of the course
     */
    function handleCourseSelection(event) {
        const selectedCourseId = event.target.value;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(selectedCourseId);
        // Filter users based on the selected course
        const filteredUsers = data.fetchData.filter(item => item.courseid === selectedCourseId);
        console.log(filteredUsers);
        const userSelect = document.getElementById('user-select');
        userSelect.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous options
        // Populate the user select element
        const userIds = [...new Set(filteredUsers.map(item => item.userid))];
        userIds.forEach(userId => {
            const option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = userId;
            option.textContent = userId;
            userSelect.appendChild(option);
        });
    }
}).fail(function(data) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(data);
});
```

this console.log(filteredUsers) is returning me empty Object

Comment: perhaps no `item.courseid` is **strictly** equal to `selectedCourseId` - note: `option.value` will be a `String`, are `item.courseid` values a string or a `Number`? ... try `==` in the filter instead of `===`

Comment: `.filter()` returns an array so it's not possible that it would log an object. `console.log(data.fetchData);` and confirm that an object exists there that should match the selectedCourseId value.

Comment: Works just fine with test data: https://jsfiddle.net/g6mey7d9/

Comment: @JaromandaX  Thanks for your response, its working now as It was number vs string matching I was doing. Thanks for your time to provide me answer
Have a good day.

Comment: @GuyIncognito Thank you for your response, but I tried with Jaromanda X solution, its working smooth but still I really appreciate that you took time to help me
Have a good day sir